# Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 w/Unity now no audio

Tags: sound, 18.04

I upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04 today and switched back to unity desktop. Now I can not get any sound out of my speakers.

The onboard sound card is detected. I've purged and reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa but haven't had any success to get sound working.

Comment: after lots of trouble shooting I have browser and spotify audio working but not the audio for skype, startup, login, test in audio control, etc, I purged alsa-base, and installed pavucontrol, in pauvucontrol > configuration > built-in audio set the profile to any of the analog outputs and it's working as stated previously. I'm not sure why but without purging alsa-base the default profile in pauvucontrol would default to a digital out which would have no audio.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simmilar problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. No program could output audio, except the system settings speaker test.

I was able to fix it by **deleting the config files** in `~/.config/pulse` and then restarting pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill`. It should restart immediately and recreate the config files with what seems to be default settings.

After that audio worked again :)

Comment: thanks, I did get it working, but can no longer remember how I did. :(